# Can a callback function occur from a previous page click (JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This may not be possible but I'm currently trying to load some JQuery from a click of a button from another page.

I very briefly know about callback functions but was wondering if a callback can be made on the new page after the click of a button from the previous page?

Comment: You could use localStorage.

Comment: The answer is no, but you can trigger code based on URL, web storage, cookies etc

Comment: It's possibly a better idea to describe exactly what you need to do, rather than focus on "callback from a previous page" because right now this sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). There might be a different solution here than trying to transfer a function over a page navigation.

Comment: "previous page" - add something to the url when you open the new page or to a form element if you go via a post.  "another page" - use sockets or latest equivalent to communicate via the server

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in `localStorage`, but sadly you need to use `eval`:

Page 1:

```
localStorage.setItem("callback", "function() { alert(42); }");
```

Page 2:

```
var callback = eval(localStorage.getItem("callback"));
callback();
```

Comment: This works but shouldn't seriously be considered as it's not good design.

Comment: Yes I know @Webber but it's the only practical way to achieve what the OP wants.

Comment: I'd say we give the OP some more time to better describe exactly what he is trying to do and where he's stuck as VLAZ pointed out. For someone saying "I very briefly know about callback functions" it's actually more useful to point in the right direction than blindly answer the question.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. so what i'm currently trying to do is:

- page 1 : display a search icon and on click navigate to page 2. 
- page 2: after click of the search icon navigate to page 2 and show a search input box on load (but the search input box should not display when navigating to this page from any other link) 

I hope that makes sense